# Objective-C: Am I Properly Using this Delegate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, tableview, nstableview

I have a mainWindowController that contains a tabView (which I'm using to switch between views on the main window).

I have view controllers (each with a nib file) for each view. One of the views, view A, contains a tableView. I need to use a delegate method to accomplish something.

After an hour or two or web research and reading up on delegates (new concept to me), I finally got my program to achieve the result I wanted it to for view A.

Here's the interface declaration for view A:

```
@interface ViewAController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDelegate>

- (BOOL) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;
```

As you can see, I'm using NSTableViewDelegate and I need to disable editing of table columns. The implementation looks like this for the method:

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSLog(@"shouldEditTableColumn called");
    return NO;
}
```

I used NSLog to make sure the function is being called.

Now in the *SAME* view controller (view A), I disable editing by clicking a button:

```
- (IBAction)turnOffEditing:(id)sender
{
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self tableView:self.tableView shouldEditTableColumn:self.columnTableName row:0];
    [self tableView:self.tableView shouldEditTableColumn:self.columnTableName row:1];
    NSLog(@"turnOffEditing");
}
```

As you can see, I get the tableView from the view controller and assign the delegate to self.

I then call the shouldEditTableColumn method on self.

Now, everything works. However, is this the correct way to use a delegate? If I need to use more delegate methods for NSTableView for view A (the only view which will have a table), I'm assuming I can define them in View A's controllers as I did previously?

Comment: Somewhere in the docs (sorry, don't have link handy) it is mentioned that `delegation` is used in lieu of subclassing (for normal functionality, my wording). This means that a delegate normally is a static part of the architecture, so changing it dynamically is a unusual. Possible, the same way it is possible to dynamically change other aspects of the class (like method implementations), but a practice reserved for special architectural challenges. I doesn't look like you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to disable table editing without a delegate method.

Comment: No, sorry, you need a delegate method, you just don't need to set the delegate dynamically in the `turnOffEditing:` method, as Ken Thomases alse mentioned in his answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Is it still "safe" to call the delegate method as I was doing? Where/how should I set the delegate appropriately?

Comment: I presume that your view controller is the nib file's owner, so you can set it in Interface Builder. Otherwise `awakeFromNib` is the traditional place to do these things if you prefer to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the delegate is the delegate from the start. That is, it's a bit strange to set the delegate in the `-turnOffEditing:` action method. Of course, for my suggestion to work, you'd want to return some dynamic value, like the value of a boolean flag instance variable, from the delegate method.

Also, you shouldn't be calling the delegate method yourself in the action method. That does nothing. The delegate is a thing which the *frameworks* call when they need to make a decision about how to behave.

So, I'd change your code to something like:

```
@property BOOL editingDisabled;

- (BOOL) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSLog(@"shouldEditTableColumn called");
    return self.editingDisabled;
}

- (IBAction)turnOffEditing:(id)sender
{
    self.editingDisabled = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"turnOffEditing");
}
```

You'd want to set the delegate during setup. A good approach is to simply connect the table view's *delegate* outlet to your controller in the NIB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Should I set the delegate in the init of the ViewA? The only controller I have in the nib is the Array Controller for values in the table.

Comment: The view controller would typically both load and serve as the owner of the NIB. Therefore, it is represented in the NIB by the File's Owner proxy object. (Be sure to set the class of File's Owner to your custom class using the Identity inspector.) So, you can connect the table view's *delegate* outlet to File's Owner to set things up.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already had the NIBs file owner as the view controller, but I didn't have the table view's delegate outlet connected. That did the trick. I also implemented your suggestion that you posted above. Works like a charm.